# Read local file from remote ssh

Tags: ssh, unix

I am running a script on a remote host using ssh

hostA shell: `cat script.sh | ssh user@hostB`

The script resides on host A and is run on host B using the above `ssh` command. So far it was good. But now the script has to read a file which also resides on the host A.

The question: Is it possible for the script to read the file from host A while running on host B?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You mean to say that you are executing a local script on a remote host using SSH and you want to read a file that is on the remote host? Can you update your post to make this clear?

Comment: No, I am executing a local script on a remote host using SSH and I want to read a file that is on the local host, i.e. the script and the file to be read by the script are both on the local host.

Answer (score 2):

You could either copy the file to the remote host (e.g. to `/tmp`) before running your script, or establish a ssh connection from the remote to the local host to get the file contents.

For the latter, you will likely need to use public-key-based authorization from the remote to the local host, so the script can run without you having to type in your password.